# Processing large input Stream to List String in Java

Tags: java

Hey I am having a file nearly 110MB size at apache. I am reading that file into input stream and then converting that input stream to List of String based on all suggestion i find on stack overflow. But still i am facing out of memory issue.
Below is my code.

```
private List<String> readFromHttp(String url, PlainDiff diff) throws Exception {
    HttpUrlConnection con = new HttpUrlConnection();
    
    con.setGetUrl(url);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    final String PREFIX = "stream2file";
    final String SUFFIX = ".tmp";

    
        final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, SUFFIX);
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        
        
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream data = con.sendGetInputStream();
        if(data==null)
            throw new UserAuthException("diff is not available at the location");

        else {
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
                IOUtils.copy(data, out);
                LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(tempFile, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        String line = it.nextLine();
                        lines.add(line);
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } finally {
                    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
                }
            }
            data.close();
            diff.setLineAsString(sb.toString());
           
            
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    //System.out.println(lines);
    
    return lines;
}




public   InputStream sendGetInputStream() throws IOException {
    
   
    String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("abc:$xyz$").getBytes("UTF-8"));

    URL obj = new URL(getGetUrl());
    
    // Setup the connection
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // Set the parameters from the headers
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    InputStream is;
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    logger.info("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
    
    
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { 
        
        is = con.getInputStream();  
    }
    
        else {
        is = null;
        
    }
    return is;
}
```

Is something in memory i am doing that is consuming lot of heap? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why? Why not process the file a line at a time? Why do you think you need it all in memory?

Comment: And what is `PlainDiff`?

Comment: This is java POJO

Comment: So are a lot of other things, but it doesn't answer any of my questions. And it's more than a POJO if it has a `setLineAsString()` method.

Comment: It's a variable in POJO. only getter setter has been used.

Comment: Dunno why you insisit on keeping it a secret, but the thing to do with it is provided the ability to add a line at a time, so you don't need the entire set of lines in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple issues. I am not going to solve each and every issue but point that out so that you can review your code and learn to write better code.

In method readFromHttp(..):

- There is no need to create a new file by `IOUtils.copy(data, out);`
- No use of String Builder `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`
- No use of line iterator `LineIterator`
- And there are multiple other memory-related issues but for the time being correct these points and test with the below-mentioned code.

Change your reading lines from file to very simple way after correcting the above mistakes:

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
       lines.add(line);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The StringBuilder is used in `diff.setLineAsString(sb.toString())`, so I'm assuming it is necessary.

Comment: No need to create temporary objects because there are various approch to convert list of string to string. For example String atr = String.join("", list); will work to create a string.

Comment: @Eran yes it is necessary to show entire file as raw code.

Comment: @AT It really doesn't matter whether you're using BufferedReader or not. It will not cost significantly much more memory as some implicitly seem to suggest. It will only improve scalability, not memory use. It will only become interesting when you've hundreds of threads running on the same file.